# passar parametros por Dialog jQuery-ui

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Boa tarde, tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
        $list = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos");
        $list->execute();
            echo '<div id="pd_list">';
                echo '<div class="head">';
                    echo '<p class="title" style="margin-top:8px; margin-left:5px; float:left; width:800px; margin-bottom:3px;">Produtos</p>';
                    echo '<form>';
                        echo '<input type="text">';
                        echo '<button><img src="../image/lupa.png" width="24"></button>';
                    echo '</form>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div id="items">';
                    foreach($list as $result):
                        echo '<div id="item">';
                            if($result['img'] != null){
                                echo '<img src="../uploads/produtos/'.$result['img'].'" width="215">';
                            }else{
                                echo '<img src="../image/fundo-produto.jpg" width="215">';
                            }
                            echo '<p style="margin-bottom:4px; float:left; margin-left:5px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; text-align:center; text-transform: uppercase; width:215px; height:40px;">'.$result['nome'].'</p>';
                            echo '<p style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:4px; float:left; margin-left:5px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px; text-align:center; width:215px; font-size:20px;">R$ '.$result['valor'].'</p>';
                            echo '<div class="opc">';
                                echo '<button id="link-excluir" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget">';
                                    echo '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>';
                                echo '</button>';
                                echo '<div id="excluir">';
                                  echo '<p>Deseja Excluir?</p>';
                                echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';

                    endforeach;

                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="holder"></div>';
            echo '</div>';

    ?>
```

com o seguinte código jQuery, utilizando o jQuery-ui Dialog:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   var opt = {
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 550,
    height:350,
    title: 'Excluir'
    };
   $( "#excluir" ).dialog(opt);

   $( "#link-excluir" ).click(function( event ) {
        $( "#excluir" ).dialog(opt).dialog( "open" );
        event.preventDefault();
    });

 $( "#link-excluir, #icons li" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
    },
    function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
    }
);
});
</script>
```

ai como podem ver utilizo foreach para exibir todos os meus resultados, e quero usar o Dialog para abrir uma caixa para exclusao, o Dialog esta funcionando perfeitamente, no entanto ele só funciona no primeiro item, os demais nao da certo, e quero passar o id do item por ele para trabalhar com ele dentro do Dialog, seja para excluir ou editar, de que maneira posso fazer isso? como pode ver a div do Dialog esta dentro do foreach. obs: sou bem leigo em JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro uma dica: Nunca utilize mais de um elemento com o mesmo ID. O ID do elemento tem que ser único, quando precisá mais de um item use a classe dele repetindo nos demais elementos.

Continuando, no php pode passar alguma referência do seu $list atual no botão, para que a função que abre o modal de excluir tenha acesso à qual elemento vc está querendo clicar:

no PHP monta o botão:

```
echo '<button class="link-excluir ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" data-ref="'.$result['id'].'">';
echo '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>';
echo '</button>';
```

No javascript vc resgata o seu elemento clicado através do this:

```
$( ".link-excluir" ).click(function( event ) {
  var ref = $(this).data('ref');
  //prossiga com sua lógica
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você deseja criar interações dinâmicas, você não pode usar id! Por isso a interação funciona somente no primeiro elemento e no restante não funciona mais!

Você deve utilizar uma classe em cada elemento e pegar os dados necessários usando $(this).parent().

Segue um exemplo com buttons onde chamo um dialogo para cada elemento

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
 
    $( ".dialog" ).on( "click", function() {
        var mensagem = $(this).attr("attr");
       $( "#dialog" ).html( mensagem);
       $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title',mensagem);
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
  </script>

</head>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Teste">
  <p></p>
</div>
 
<button  class="dialog" id="opener" attr="TESTE 1">Open Dialog 1</button>
 <button class="dialog" id="opener" attr="TESTE 2">Open Dialog 2</button>
 <button class="dialog" id="opener" attr="TESTE 3">Open Dialog 3</button>
 <button class="dialog" id="opener" attr="TESTE 4" >Open Dialog 4</button>
 <button class="dialog" id="opener" attr="TESTE 5">Open Dialog 5</button>
 <button class="dialog" id="opener" attr="TESTE 6">Open Dialog 6</button>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```